# Ionic & Angular - best resources

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile

I'm about to begin with new project (using Ionic framework and Angular 5).
There are dozens of tutorials on Internet, so I ask for advice, which ones are best to start? I don't have experience with Angular (2,4,5) and Typescript so I need something to dig into Typescript, Angular and then into Ionic...maybe Udemy courses?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is a good place to ask this question when you can google it / find on Quora or another forum with hundreds of links with "best to learn from".

if you're into udemy courses then I would suggest going with Maximilian Schwarzmüller courses. From what I remember his main angular course has typescript section too or even different course just for typescript if you want to dive even deeper. Don't think about ionic when you're at the start of your angular journey.

To be honest, before you start spending on courses or search any extra materials just dive into angular docs and do their tutorial. It should be your first step.

There is no perfect answer for your question - it depends on what kind of person you are and which way of learning is best for you.